# Core dumped after program exits

Tags: c, linux

I have a quite intriguing issue with my program (compiled with gcc 4.6.4 on ubuntu 12.04). When I dynamically build the executable, the program runs flawlessly. But when I build it statically (with -static flag), it gives me a 'core dumped' after exiting (e.g. after 'return 0' in main). Unfortunately, the whole program is too big to pose in here. What are the possibilities?

Answer (score 2):

In addition of the two possibilities in [johnnycrash answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24240036/841108):

- Some functions with [`__attribute__ ((destructor))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) is called, and dump core.
- The memory heap is corrupted (check with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/))
- Some function registered with [atexit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) is crashing
- Some library/function is linked "twice"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Somehow, replacing 'return 0' by '_exit(0)' resolves the issue.

Comment: That bypasses the issue without solving it.

Answer (score 1):

1) You have a thread still executing.
2) You are overwriting memory and you get lucky with the dynamic libraries.

Comment: You are using dynamic libraries rather than static libraries for the static version of the link.